# Letter decode Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will validate that all entries within the commas are numberic and display "?" if they are not.    for example:   user enters 2,3,5b,c7 the output that I am getting is BCE?  instead of BC??  This is the decode function that I am trying to validate in:

```
function fnDecode() {
    var msg = $("textin").value;
        if(msg === "") {
        $("textin_span").innerHTML = "* Please enter a value to decode 
              *";
        $("textin").focus();
    return;
    } else {
        $("textin_span").innerHTML = "";
    }
    var nums = msg.split(","); //split method separates by delimiter
    var outstr = ""; //out string

    for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        var n2 = parseInt(nums[i]);
        if (isNaN(n2)) { //if isNaN true, print ?

        outstr += "?";
        } else if (isNallN(nums[i])) { //THIS IS WHERE THE FN GOES
            outstr += "?";

        } else if (n2 === 0) {
            outstr += " ";
        } else if (n2 < 1 || n2 >26) {
            outstr += "?";
        }else {
            outstr += String.fromCharCode(n2+64);
        }
    }
    $("textout").value = outstr;

}

function isNallN(s) {
}
```

Comment: And what would be the required output?

Comment: it looks like your `isNallN()` ought to just be the preexisting `isNaN()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected your `fnDecode` function.

You don't need multiple `if` to check for `isNaN`, `!isNaN('5')` will work as well as `!isNaN(5)`. Check this [Javascript Equality Table](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/unified/) for more information.

> Here, I adapted the function for it to work with a `String` given in
>   parameter and to return the wanted `String`.

```js
function fnDecode(msg) {
  var nums = msg.split(",");
  var outstr = "";

  for (num of nums) {
    if (isNaN(num)) outstr += "?"; //isNaN works on "5" and 5
    else if (+num === 0) outstr += " "; //We use +num to parse the String to an int
    else if (+num < 1 || +num > 26) outstr += "?";
    else outstr += String.fromCharCode(+num + 64);
  }
  return outstr;

}

var test = '1,2,3,4,5f,6r';
console.log(fnDecode(test));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Here is a shorter ES6 version :

```js
function fnDecode(msg) {
  return msg.split(',').map( num => isNaN(num) || (+num < 1 || +num > 26) ? '?' : +num == 0 ? ' ' : String.fromCharCode(+num + 64)).join('');
}

var test = '1,2,3,4,5f,6r';
console.log(fnDecode(test));
```